# Music video playing on laptop as input to microphone

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, microphone

I'm playing a video on my laptop which is running Windows 10. I want to broadcast that video's sounds to my microphone so that the person at the other end listening to my microphone listens to the videos playing on my laptop. Is that possible?

The music video is, I suppose, an .mp3 file which is playing on my computer and which I can clearly hear on my speakers, but I want to broadcast the same sound to others listening to my microphone on other computers. Is there some special software required for this?

The problem is I am using earphones connected my computer so that the sound is not emitted through speakers and cannot be picked up by the mike, so is there some internal thingy possible?

Comment: You may wish to edit your question to clarify what software you are using to broadcast with (i.e. how are others listening to your "microphone"?).

Comment: It's in-game microphone usage.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the sound output, go to control panel > hardware and sound > sound > then change the output.

Comment: A bit more detail please